# Modeling three phase load for EV charger

Tags: current, transformer, three-phase, line

When designing a power system to supply EV charging stations, are the stations modeled as delta loads or wye loads? Slightly off topic but is it standard practice to assume that three phase loads are Delta configured? Wye configured? I am working on deriving transformer lines currents from connected load currents.

Comment: We most frequently use Wye - Wye or Wye - Delta

Comment: The Type 2 charger socket has provision for three phases and a neutral, so that should be a clue.

Comment: OP doesnt say anything about type 2 chargers.

Comment: If you have a 1 kilowatt load in a 230V/400V three phase system, isn't it still a 1 kilowatt load no matter how you connect it, and so the currents will be equal too?

Comment: I am dealing with both level 2 and level 3 chargers. The systems I deal with have both single phase level two chargers and three phase level 3 chargers so the currents are not balanced.